# How to add vertical and horizontal scollbar to my MainFrame on wxpython

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, scrollbar

Panels are dynamically added during the execution of the program. How do I add a Scrollbar to my MainFrame when it is initialized so that I can see the panels added below each other?

```
import wx
 
 
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(None, *args, **kwargs)
        self.Title = 'Wx App'
        screen_width, screen_height = wx.GetDisplaySize()
        win_width = min(screen_width, 1280)
        win_height = min(screen_height, 800)
        self.Size = (win_width, win_height)
 
        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.panel)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Center()
        self.Show()
 
 
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
 
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    wx_app = wx.App()
    MainFrame()
    wx_app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Your code here is only a stub ([a copy of this](https://pastebin.com/pn86mFiK)). Is it NOT a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (please read this link). We cannot see where and how you wish to add the panels or where and how you expect your scroll bars to look, or what attempt you have made to display scroll bars. Please put yourself in the place of the person trying to answer the question; they are not mind readers. BTW there is no need to create a new user identity for each question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a solution with wx.ScrolledWindow but a scrolled panel seems to work.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel as scrolled

class MyForm(wx.Frame):
     
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Tutorial", size=(800,600))
 
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour('green')
        
        self.scrolled_panel = scrolled.ScrolledPanel(self.panel, -1, style = wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER, name="panel1")
        self.scrolled_panel.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.scrolled_panel.SetupScrolling()
        self.scrolled_panel.SetBackgroundColour('CYAN')
        
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        text = wx.StaticText(self.scrolled_panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'My text')
        self.sizer.Add(text)
        
        panel_in1 = wx.Panel(self.scrolled_panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(-1,250), style = wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        panel_in1.SetBackgroundColour('red')
        self.sizer.Add(panel_in1,0,wx.EXPAND)
        
        panel_in2 = wx.Panel(self.scrolled_panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(-1,150), style = wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        panel_in2.SetBackgroundColour('grey')
        self.sizer.Add(panel_in2,0,wx.EXPAND)
        
        self.scrolled_panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        
        panelSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panelSizer.AddSpacer(50)
        panelSizer.Add(self.scrolled_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.SetSizer(panelSizer)
        
        self.statusBar = self.CreateStatusBar( 1, wx.STB_SIZEGRIP, wx.ID_ANY )
        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: A simple scrolledpanel example is given here [wxpython] (https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.scrolledpanel.html)